# i want to see if there is no repetitive day insert it into newArr that is the case (only if() part)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

```js
const arr = ["monday","tuesday","thursday","wednesday",
  "friday","saturday","sunday"];
let newArr = [];
var num = prompt('Enter number :');
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var day = prompt('Enter day :');
  if(newArr.includes(day) !== day) newArr.push(day);
}
var num = prompt('Enter number :');
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var day = prompt('Enter day :');
  if(newArr.includes(day) != day) newArr.push(day);
}
console.log(7 - (newArr.length));
```

i only want to know if() part
if we entered a repetitive day like friday twice push it once into the newArr
for example  1 | friday  &  1 | friday   ---- >  6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to check the entered day is present in the array, and if no, push the element to `newArr`, change your if condition to:

```js
if(!newArr.includes(day))
{
  ...
}
```